# which of the following are dense?6

Tags: general-topology

[image]

My attempt ; for option a)i  know that the cantor set is uncountable and it has measure Zero(0).It is nowhere dense .therfore it will not dense .so option a) is not dense

for option b) according to Stone–Weierstrass theorem , it will be dense . so option b) is dense

for option c) i know that by fourier series {sinnt} is dense. So option c) is dense

therfore  only option b) and option c) are correct ,,,,

Is my answer is correct or not. Pliz tell me the  solution ....

Comment: What makes you think that a) is the Cantor set? Or do you think countability affects density directly? The rational numbers are dense, so that assumption is clearly wrong. And Stone-Weierstrass doesn't help in b), since that's about the sup-norm on functions on a closed set, while you have $L^1$ norm on an open interval.

Comment: option a) is cantor set,,,,@ arthur ,,,,it  endpoints are  countable,,,

Comment: But $\frac12$ is in the set in a), but not in the Cantor set. So clearly they cannot be the same.

Comment: For (a), graph the set on the number line, for $n = 1,2,3$, and you'll see what that set is all about.

Answer (score 3):

a) The set is not the Cantor set, to the point of it actually being dense in $[0,1]$.

b) It is true that restrictions of polynomials are dense in $L^1(0,1)$; it is a *consequence* of Stone-Weierstrass, but not quite that theorem, which is about density in $(C[0,1],\lVert\bullet\rVert_\infty)$ rather than $(L^1[0,1],\lVert\bullet\rVert_1)$

c) You might know that $\{\sin(nt)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Hilbert basis of $L^2(0,\pi)$, but it is definitely not a Hilbert basis of $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. For instance, the closure of its span does not contain $\cos t$.

Comment: im not getting for option c) as i know that sin(nt) is hilbert basis @G.Sassatelli......but for option C)  it is true,by Fejér's theorem.,,,,,,,

Comment: can u more  elaborate ..option C)@ G.Sassatelli

Comment: Fejér's theorem says that the sequence of Cesaro sums of the partial Fourier series of a continuous function $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$ converges uniformly to $f$. Fourier series is that thing when you write $f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\Bbb R$ as $$\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\cos(kt)+b_k\sin(kt)$$
"I know $\sin(nt)$ is Hilbert basis": since you do not know **of which space**, you know nothing.

Comment: thank u so  much @ G.sassatelli  for providing me solution.......exactly actually im very weak in functional analysis  and topology..im very sorry for that comment that sinnt is a hilbert basis....